# Передача переменных в вид в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, переменные, codeigniter

Здравствуйте Уважаемые Программисты. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать передачу параметра (массив `get content($title)`) в вид. При передаче параметра третьим сегментом, контетнт, и др., параметры выводятся без ошибок. Но при этом используется только один вид. А мне необходимо несколько разных представлений. Т е. необходимо передать параметры вторым сегментом. Файлы конроллера, модели и видов прилагаю...
Спасибо.С уважением Владимир

```
**контроллер**

 public function index($title)
    {
        $data['menu'] = $this->pages_model->get_menu();               
        $data['content'] = $this->pages_model->get_content($title);
        $this->load->view("head_view", $data); 
        $this->load->view("main_view",  $data);
    }
**модель**

public function get_content($title)
        {
            $this->db->where('title_url',$title);            
            $query = $this->db->get('settings'); 
            return $query->row_array();  
        } 
    **ссылка в виде (по циклу foreach)**

    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/pages/<?=$item['title_url'];?>"><?=$item['title'];?></a></li>
    **Вывожу в виде main_view**

 <h2><?=$content['title'];?></h2>
 <?=$content['content'];?>
```

Comment: а вы и не передаете $title.

Comment: Здравствуйте Уважаемый Vfvtnjd. Я понимаю что не передаю параметр в вид. Но мне нужно как-то передать. В общем мне нужно вывести контент из базы, соответствующий вызываемому виду, по динамической ссылке. Или может существует другой способ решения. Если подскажете- буду очень признателен.
Спасибо.С Уважением Владимир

Answer (score 1):

Ну, так и передайте:

```
$this->load->view("head_view", $data['menu']); 
$this->load->view("main_view",  $data['content']);
```

Comment: $data['title'] = 'Заголовок';
и все, в чем проблема. Вам же массив данных никто не запрещает передавать